# How to call a method inside the same method only once

Tags: java

I'm trying to make blackjack where if the ace + other card > 21, the ace's value is 1 instead of 11. Everything worked until I added that part so I believe it's looping itself since it's using the method in itself. What do I do differently?

```
public class CardValue implements Listener {

    @SuppressWarnings({"ConstantConditions", "unused", "SimplifiableIfStatement"})

    //HandValue handValue = new HandValue();
    public int getCardValue(final Player player, final int cardPos, final Plugin plugin) {

        int cardValue = 0;

            List<String> types = Arrays.asList("Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King");
            for(String type : types) {
                if(plugin.getConfig().getList(player.getName() + "'s game deck").get(cardPos).toString().contains(type)) {
                    switch (type) {
                        case "Ace":
                            cardValue = 11;
                            if(getCardValue(player,1,plugin) + getCardValue(player,3,plugin) > 21) {
                                cardValue = 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Two":
                            cardValue = 2;
                            break;
                        case "Three":
                            cardValue = 3;
                            break;
                        case "Four":
                            cardValue = 4;
                            break;
                        case "Five":
                            cardValue = 5;
                            break;
                        case "Six":
                            cardValue = 6;
                            break;
                        case "Seven":
                            cardValue = 7;
                            break;
                        case "Eight":
                            cardValue = 8;
                            break;
                        case "Nine":
                            cardValue = 9;
                            break;
                        case "Ten": case "Jack": case "Queen": case "King":
                            cardValue = 10;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cardValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by looping itself? You're calling your method recursively twice when the value is Ace, but what is the result? 
Also what do you mean by doing differently? Compared to what?

Comment: Also, try to set a debug point to the Ace case and check out what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a flag (or flags since you may get two or more ace?), don't give 1 or 11 inside "case "Ace". Do scoring after all is done.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe this might not be a legit way to solve it*

**But it works fine and you can give it a try**

Initialize a variable outside the getCardValue() method

```
int b=0;
```

Then change your getCardValue() method to

```
case "Ace":
     cardValue = 11;
if(b==0)
{
  b=1;
  int a=getCardValue(player,1,plugin) + getCardValue(player,3,plugin) ;
  b=0;
  if(a> 21) {
  cardValue = 1;
  } 
}
break;
```

So basically here b=0 as default and when the card is ace it satisfies the condition `b==0` and then calls the method again but before doing that it sets b=1...

So when it comes back here again ( the ace with the condition and method call). The condition `if(b==0)` is false as 'b' was set to 1... so it does not execute the code inside `if(b==0)`

Then after you have the returned value in variable 'a' the next line gets execute that is `b=0;` and then `if(a> 21) { cardValue = 1; }`